# Disable form controls based on previous selections

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I have a table where a column in each row consists of the same `<select>` option like this:

```
<tr>
....
<td>..</td>
<td>
    <select id="gender">
        <option value="M">Male</option>
        <option value="F">Female</option>
    </select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
....
<td>..</td>
<td>
    <select id="gender">
        <option value="M">Male</option>
        <option value="F">Female</option>
    </select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
....
<td>..</td>
<td>
    <select id="gender">
        <option value="M">Male</option>
        <option value="F">Female</option>
    </select>
</td>
</tr>
```

Lets say i'm currently working on the second row, how do I disable the option on the third row?

Comment: Note that your html is invalid: `id` is supposed to be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this).closest("tr").next().find("select").prop("disabled", true);
```

Use the `closest("selector")` method to traverse up to the parent (you could also use `parents("selector")`), jump to the next one using `next()`, traverse down to `find("selector")` and edit the form element with `prop()`.

Of course, you'd put this line in some kind of event handler, probably a `change` event fired by the previous `select` element. However, before you do that, you'll need to make sure you're not doubling up on `id`'s...otherwise jQuery won't work so well.

Comment: i have tried it in console, i got warning `prop()` is not a function. but i get the next id

Comment: `.prop()` was added in jQuery 1.6 - if you're using an earlier version, use `.attr()` instead. `.attr("disabled", "disabled")`